# How can I uninstall Windows 7 RC(build) and revert to Vista?

Tags: windows-7

I have a secondary laptop that is still "running" Windows 7 Ultimate trial (build 7100) that I installed on top of Windows Vista.

I bought a Windows 7 Home Premium Upgrade and intended to upgrade the trial to the activated version but it just blue screens.

Anyone know the proper procedure?  Should I try to uninstall the trial first?

Comment: Not sure if this will work for rolling back to Vista, might be worth a try....http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933168/en-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't "uninstall" an operating system and go back to an older one. It's a one-way operation.

If you want to go back to Vista, you will have to reinstall it using your Windows CD, Restore CD, or recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

It would make sense to uninstall the trial first - especially as it's so old. However, the install may be in such a state that a reformat might be the best option. That way you'd have a clean installation of the OS.

Actually I'm not sure if you can uninstall the trial - though it should have renamed Vista's `Windows` directory to `Windows.Old`. If you get to the point where you're about to reformat you could try renaming that back to `Windows` and see if you get Vista.

As you have the upgrade you may need to re-install Vista as well.

Comment: Any idea where in Windows 7 the trial is uninstalled?  I didn't see it under installed programs.  Is there a specific utility for that?

Comment: @user80237 - sorry, I never installed the trial.